# How do I make a parenthetical citation for a speech?

Tags: citations

I'm writing a position paper and wanted to quote part of [Martin Luther King, Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King_Jr.).'s famous "[I Have a Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_a_Dream)" speech, but I'm not quite sure what to cite: the speech, or the website I got it from? And then what should I put in the parenthesis after the indented quote? Right now I have: (Paragraph 8) but that's hardly adequate. Help will be much appreciated.

The site with the speech: https://www.americanrhetoric.com/speeches/mlkihaveadream.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, first, how to reference the speech as a whole; second, the provide a pinpoint reference (if possible) to the words you want to quote.

The first problem is easily solved. You should reference the source on which you relied for the information. In this case, that's the [American Rhetoric](https://www.americanrhetoric.com) website, with a more [direct link to the actual speech](https://www.americanrhetoric.com/speeches/mlkihaveadream.htm). How exactly you should write the reference will depend upon the kind of referencing and citation style that you have decided to use, or the style that is required by a publisher (if you are publishing your work).

As to the problem of producing a pinpoint reference, I think that the best yo can do is exactly what you have proposed; namely, refer to paragraph 8 of the speech. Obviously, the division of the speech into paragraphs is dependent upon the decisions made by whoever did the transcription, but if you refer to the webpage then the reference should be interpreted by an intelligent reader as being a reference to paragraph 8 *on that page*.